# Randomly select a link from a list with mod_rewrite/rewritecond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 30 separate external urls, each with a different landing page variation, and I want to serve one up at random on a click.

Ideally, repeat clicks would be guaranteed a different url than they were served already, but not a strict requirement, this would be great though if possible.

I've seen examples of people using rewrite/writecond to split test based on the odd/even timestamp of the click, or based on the numbers in their ip address, but this wouldn't really accomplish this task.

I would strongly prefer to do this within the httpd server itself without relying on a python/php script, and I feel like this must be possible, I just haven't been able to find a solution so far.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in rewrite?  It seems like code is the right tool for this job.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller mostly a preference to keep everything within httpd without any external dependencies to accomplish the task, partially i think it would be cool and tidy to be able to do so, partially because i would need to pay for any script to be created and modified in the future by a 3rd party